# Using OneToOneField in Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm realized some models in application:

```
from django.db import models

class Commentary(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created_date = models.DateField()
    comment = models.TextField()

class Role(models.Model):
    role_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class User(models.Model):
    login = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    email = models.EmailField()
    role_id = models.OneToOneField(Role)
```

After that typed in console "python manage.py makemigration mainws" for making migrations in my database, however, taken stacktrace with error. If looking in [django documentation for one-to-one example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/), we can see the similarity with him, but without option `primary_key=True`.  How can I fix this or maybe better using `ForeignKey` with `unique=True` for this issue, or something other?

Stacktrace:

```
=> python manage.py makemigration mainws
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/savicvalera/code/lab8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/savicvalera/code/lab8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/savicvalera/code/lab8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/savicvalera/code/lab8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/Users/savicvalera/code/lab8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/savicvalera/code/lab8/website/mainws/models/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import Commentary, MailList, Product, Provider, Rate, Review, Role, Sale, ShoppingCart, Status, Supplies, User
  File "/Users/savicvalera/code/lab8/website/mainws/models/Commentary.py", line 11, in <module>
    from . import Product, User
  File "/Users/savicvalera/code/lab8/website/mainws/models/User.py", line 14, in <module>
    class User(models.Model):
  File "/Users/savicvalera/code/lab8/website/mainws/models/User.py", line 21, in User
    role_id = models.OneToOneField(Role,to_field='id')
  File "/Users/savicvalera/code/lab8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1799, in __init__
    super(OneToOneField, self).__init__(to, to_field, OneToOneRel, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/savicvalera/code/lab8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1612, in __init__
    assert isinstance(to, six.string_types), "%s(%r) is invalid. First parameter to ForeignKey must be either a model, a model name, or the string %r" % (self.__class__.__name__, to, RECURSIVE_RELATIONSHIP_CONSTANT)
AssertionError: OneToOneField(<module 'mainws.models.Role' from '/Users/savicvalera/code/lab8/website/mainws/models/Role.pyc'>) is invalid. First parameter to ForeignKey must be either a model, a model name, or the string u'self'
```

Comment: have you imported Role in User.py ?

Comment: Yes, of course. I just made one *.py file per model.

Comment: As a side note, don't suffix your related fields with `_id`. Django will automatically create an attribute with that suffix pointing to the id. For example, right now a `Commentary` instance has `user_id` pointing to a `User` instance and `user_id_id` pointing to the actual id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your code organization correctly, the problem is in your imports. When you say

```
from . import Role
```

you're importing `Role.py` into a module object named `Role`. Inside that module (I assume) is your `Role` model class. So what you really want is:

```
from .Role import Role
```

Or:

```
from . import Role

...
role_id = models.OneToOneField(Role.Role)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define an `app_label` in your meta class

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'mainws'
```